# Using Pandas to filter 2 specific day of year

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a big CSV dataset and i wish to filter my dataset with use of Pandas and save it into new CSV File

The aim is to find all the records for 1 and 15 days of the year

when i used following code it is work

```
print (df[(df['data___date_time'].dt.day == 1)])
```

and result appear as follow:

```
         data___date_time       NO2       SO2   PM10
26    2020-07-01 00:00:00  1.591616  0.287604    NaN
27    2020-07-01 01:00:00  1.486401       NaN    NaN
28    2020-07-01 02:00:00  1.362056       NaN    NaN
29    2020-07-01 03:00:00  1.295101  0.194399    NaN
30    2020-07-01 04:00:00  1.260667  0.362168    NaN
                  ...       ...       ...    ...
17054 2022-07-01 19:00:00  2.894369  2.077140  19.34
17055 2022-07-01 20:00:00  3.644265  1.656386  23.09
17056 2022-07-01 21:00:00  2.907760  1.291555  23.67
17057 2022-07-01 22:00:00  2.974715  1.318185  27.68
17058 2022-07-01 23:00:00  2.858022  1.169057  25.18
```

However when i used following code nothing comes out

```
print (df[(df['data___date_time'].dt.day == 1) & (df['data___date_time'].dt.day == 15)])
```

this just gave me:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [data___date_time, NO2, SO2, PM10]
Index: []
```

Is there any idea what could be the problem

Comment: You need `|` instead of `&`. A day cannot be **both** on 1 and 15

Comment: @NuriTaş Thank you very much, your hint solve my problem

Comment: @NuriTaş
my problem solve, as you said i had a logical problem, i should used | instead of &

but i wondering to know if i want to had a mean of each day what should i do
i mean:

for example mean values of 
day 1 for January 2020 and day 15 for January 2020
day 1 for February 2020 and day 15 for February 2020
...
day 1 for December 2022 and day 15 for December 2022

Answer (score 0):

There is logical problem, is not possible same row `1` and `15`, need `|` for `bitwise OR`. If need test multiple values simplier is use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data___date_time': pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=20)})

print (df[df['data___date_time'].dt.day.isin([1,15])]) 
   data___date_time
0        2000-01-01
14       2000-01-15
```

Comment: Here my problem solve, as you said i had a logical problem, i should used | instead of &
but i wondering to know if i want to had a mean of each day what should i do
i mean:

for example mean values of 
day 1 for January 2020 and day 15 for January 2020
day 1 for February 2020 and day 15 for February 2020
...
day 1 for December 2022 and day 15 for December 2022

Comment: @kamyar1986 Sure, use `df1 =  df[df['data___date_time'].dt.day.isin([1,15])]` and then `out = df1.groupby(df1['data___date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')). mean() `

Comment: Dear @jezrael
i hade one more question, based on what you tell me i developed code. i have several dataset some and i want to extract specific headers and then rename it. However some of dataset dosent have that specific header. How should i ignore this process in my code

Comment: My code is  `dfLarnaca_TS = pd.read_csv('Larnaca_TS_290620_020722.json_json-csv-xls.com_dy.csv', usecols = ['data___date_time','data___pollutant_8','data___pollutant_5','data___pollutant_1'])
dfLarnaca_TS.rename({'data___date_time': 'DateTime','data___pollutant_8': 'No2', 'data___pollutant_5': 'PM10', 'data___pollutant_1': 'So2'}, axis = "columns", inplace = True)`